# Why are black&white images inverted in image processing?

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing

My use case is to detect the angle a black&white scanned image is rotated. Most image processing algorithms I am finding online as a first step do a bitwise not on the image so that the background is black and the objects white.
  My questions is what is the reason behind this? I cannot find any other answers that this is how it is done in image processing.

Thank you.

Comment: The reason is that black=0 means false and >0 means true in c++ so a binary mask says black = not part of the mask (false) and white = part of the mask (true). The only exception I know in openCV is distanceTransform input where 0 means 0 distance from foreground so foreground elements are expected to be 0 masked there.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across two reasons for doing this inversion:

**1)** Inverted image sometimes gives better interpretation (eg. in medical image analysis)

[image: Digital Image Processing - by rafael gonzalez]

**2)** When background region of the image capture (black in colour) is needed for segmentation as mentioned in this problem

[Problems with line detection in Emgu CV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26957756/problems-with-line-detection-in-emgu-cv)